# Using INNER JOIN to Find Similar DATA-My MyProblem:Repeating some results

Tags: sql-server

I am using this query to find similar results in two tables, however some of the data repeat themselves, and I have no idea what might the problem be.
Could you please check this query, to see if there is something I did wrong or not.

All sorts of join(inner,left,right and join alone! returned the same results)

```
select dbo.netss.[CODE]
      ,dbo.netss.[NUM]
      ,dbo.netss.[state]
      ,dbo.netss.[county]
      ,dbo.netss.[zone]
      ,dbo.netss.[Mvillage]
      ,dbo.netss.[Village]
      ,dbo.netss.[operator]
      ,dbo.P1.*
from dbo.P1
inner join
dbo.netss
on (dbo.netss.[state]=dbo.p1.[state])
where dbo.P1.Name=dbo.netss.Village
```

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the result you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Duplicates? Try `SELECT DISTINCT`

Answer (score 0):

Joining on `[state]` is probably not what you want.  If the values in the `[state]` column are not unique in both tables, then you will get multiple matches from dbo.p1 to dbo.netss and possibly from dbo.netss to dbo.p1 also.  Add more columns to your join list as follows, for example:

```
on dbo.netss.[state] = dbo.p1.[state] and dbo.netss.[county] = dbo.p1.[county] and dbo.netss.[CODE] = dbo.netss.[CODE]
```

In other words, join on the combination of columns that make a row unique and that are also in the other table.  This will define a unique key in one table that can be a foreign key to the other table.

Comment: Do you mean that no combination of values is unique?  It is not required that a single column be unique.  If no combination of columns is unique, then the problem is in the design of the database schema.  Table designs that are normalized to a reasonable level will have unique keys.  Table designs that are well implemented will have unique constraints to enforce the uniqueness of these keys.

Answer (score 0):

```
--You Can try this
select DISTINCT
       dbo.netss.[CODE]
      ,dbo.netss.[NUM]
      ,dbo.netss.[state]
      ,dbo.netss.[county]
      ,dbo.netss.[zone]
      ,dbo.netss.[Mvillage]
      ,dbo.netss.[Village]
      ,dbo.netss.[operator]
      ,dbo.P1.*
from dbo.P1
inner join
dbo.netss
on (dbo.netss.[state]=dbo.p1.[state])
where dbo.P1.Name=dbo.netss.Village
----the DISTINCT keywords do eliminate duplicate
```